# "Update Internet Password When Notes Client Password Changes" sometimes doesn't work

Tags: passwords, lotus-domino

We are running Domino 9.0 and have running the policy "Update Internet Password When Notes Client Password Changes". This works *most* of the time. But once in awhile a user will change their password and the Sametime/Internet password does NOT change.

Any idea about under what conditions this would occur?

Is there any way to monitor to see if these are out of sync?

Comment: what does admin4.nsf say?

Comment: This queston belongs on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.